# Filter out a word from a line

Tags: ksh

I would like to get out a word(number) from the line below but via a very simple one linear command 
Needed string is 260.796, so I just would like to get 260.796 out of below line

```
xcxalpha=0.000 es enealpha=260.796 es emalpha=29.107 es
```

Comment: I used grep alpha file|awk -F'enealpha=' '{print $2}'|awk {'print $1'}

Comment: but needed better

Comment: any help teams pls

Comment: appreciate any help in this

Answer (score 0):

You must think how you know what part of the string you want.
When you want the substring after the second '=' until the space, use

```
echo "xcxalpha=0.000 es enealpha=260.796 es emalpha=29.107 es" | cut -d "=" -f3 | cut -d " " -f1
```

When you want the value after `enealpha=`, use

```
echo "xcxalpha=0.000 es enealpha=260.796 es emalpha=29.107 es" | sed 's/.*enealpha=//;s/ .*//'
```

or

```
echo "xcxalpha=0.000 es enealpha=260.796 es emalpha=29.107 es" | sed -r 's/.*enealpha=([^ ]*).*/\1/'
```

When the spaces and equal signs are like the example, you might consider them as field sep's like

```
echo "xcxalpha=0.000 es enealpha=260.796 es emalpha=29.107 es" | awk -F " |=" '{print $5}'
```

When you want something else, look for the right `sed/awk/cut` command/combination.